Sequelize transactions are very slow
I'm using sequelize with node to make a simple update endpoint that will make a couple of queries:
const update = async (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    const t = await db.sequelize.transaction();
    // const t2 = await db.sequelize.transaction();

    try {
        const model = {
            ...req.body,
            user_id: req.user.id,
        };

        let isPause = false;
        if (model.description && model.description == 'operation_types.pause') isPause = true;

        const data = await db.Operation.scope(
            isPause ? {} : { method: ['companyScope', req] }
        ).findByPk(req.params.id, {
            hooks: false,
            include: [
                {
                    model: db.Task,
                    as: 'task',
                },
            ],
        });

        if (!data) throw new ResolveError(ResponsesEnums.NOT_FOUND, 404);
        await data.update(model, { transaction: t });

        const company = await db.Company.findByPk(req.user.company_id ?? data.task.company_id);
        const fileUpload = new FileUploadJob();

        if (req.files && req.files.length > 0) {
            for (const file of req.files) {
                fileUpload.addJob(
                    JobsNamesEnums.UPLOAD_FILE,
                    { entity: data, file, company },
                    { timeout: 120000 }
                );
            }
        }

        let resourceId;

        if (req.body.resource_id) resourceId = req.body.resource_id;
        if (req.resource_id) resourceId = req.resource_id;
        if (model.operation && model.operation.resource_id)
            resourceId = model.operation.resource_id;

        if (resourceId) {
            const resource = await db.Resource.findByPk(resourceId);
            if (!resource) throw new ResolveError(ResponsesEnums.NOT_FOUND, 404);

            if (model.lat && model.lng) {
                await resource.update(
                    { lat: parseFloat(model.lat), lng: parseFloat(model.lng) },
                    { transaction: t }
                );
            }

            const activation = await resource.sendHandleActivation();

            if (activation && !activation.operation_id) {
                const activationModel = await db.ResourceActivation.findByPk(activation.id);
                await activationModel.update({ operation_id: data.id });
            } else if (!activation) {
                throw new ResolveError('Impossible to activate the resource', 400);
            }
        }

        // If model.stop and has an linked_operation_id, update the linked operation
        if (req.body.stop && model.stop && data.linked_operation_id) {
            const linkedOperation = await db.Operation.findByPk(data.linked_operation_id);
            if (linkedOperation) {
                await linkedOperation.update({ stop: model.stop });
            }
        }

        await t.commit();
        return res.send(data);
    } catch (error: any) {
        logError(error);
        await t.rollback();
        return next(error);
    }
};


The problem here is that if I pass the transaction to my operation.update and resource.update it will take > 50s to execute, but if I avoid passing it, it will take < 1s.
This is to say that the queries are pretty basic and don't take much to execute them.
Does anybody have a solution for this?

The issue you're experiencing with the transaction taking longer than expected (more than 50 seconds) when passed to operation.update and resource.update is likely related to how Sequelize handles transactions and connections in the pool, as well as potential locking or resource contention issues. Here are a few possible causes and solutions based on your scenario:
1. Connection Pooling and Transaction Contention
Sequelize uses a connection pool to manage database connections efficiently. When you use transactions, each transaction requires a dedicated connection from the pool. If your pool size is small or there are too many concurrent transactions, it can cause delays because Sequelize has to wait for an available connection.
Solution: Increase Connection Pool Size
You can try increasing the connection pool size in your Sequelize configuration to allow more concurrent transactions:
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  // other options...
  pool: {
    max: 20, // Increase this value based on your server's capacity
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000, // Wait up to 30 seconds for a connection
    idle: 10000, // Release idle connections after 10 seconds
  },
});

This will help if your app is running many concurrent transactions that are waiting for available connections.
2. Managed Transactions
Sequelize supports managed transactions, which automatically handle committing or rolling back transactions based on whether an error occurs. This can simplify your code and potentially improve performance by reducing manual transaction management.
Instead of manually starting and committing/rolling back the transaction, you could refactor your code to use a managed transaction:
const update = async (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    try {
        const result = await db.sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
            const model = {
                ...req.body,
                user_id: req.user.id,
            };

            let isPause = false;
            if (model.description && model.description == 'operation_types.pause') isPause = true;

            const data = await db.Operation.scope(
                isPause ? {} : { method: ['companyScope', req] }
            ).findByPk(req.params.id, {
                hooks: false,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: db.Task,
                        as: 'task',
                    },
                ],
                transaction: t, // Ensure this query uses the transaction
            });

            if (!data) throw new ResolveError(ResponsesEnums.NOT_FOUND, 404);
            await data.update(model, { transaction: t });

            const company = await db.Company.findByPk(req.user.company_id ?? data.task.company_id);

            const fileUpload = new FileUploadJob();
            if (req.files && req.files.length > 0) {
                for (const file of req.files) {
                    fileUpload.addJob(
                        JobsNamesEnums.UPLOAD_FILE,
                        { entity: data, file, company },
                        { timeout: 120000 }
                    );
                }
            }

            let resourceId;
            if (req.body.resource_id) resourceId = req.body.resource_id;
            if (req.resource_id) resourceId = req.resource_id;
            if (model.operation && model.operation.resource_id)
                resourceId = model.operation.resource_id;

            if (resourceId) {
                const resource = await db.Resource.findByPk(resourceId);
                if (!resource) throw new ResolveError(ResponsesEnums.NOT_FOUND, 404);

                if (model.lat && model.lng) {
                    await resource.update(
                        { lat: parseFloat(model.lat), lng: parseFloat(model.lng) },
                        { transaction: t }
                    );
                }

                const activation = await resource.sendHandleActivation();
                if (activation && !activation.operation_id) {
                    const activationModel = await db.ResourceActivation.findByPk(activation.id);
                    await activationModel.update({ operation_id: data.id }, { transaction: t });
                } else if (!activation) {
                    throw new ResolveError('Impossible to activate the resource', 400);
                }
            }

            if (req.body.stop && model.stop && data.linked_operation_id) {
                const linkedOperation = await db.Operation.findByPk(data.linked_operation_id);
                if (linkedOperation) {
                    await linkedOperation.update({ stop: model.stop }, { transaction: t });
                }
            }

            return data; // Return the updated data
        });

        return res.send(result);
    } catch (error) {
        logError(error);
        return next(error);
    }
};

3. Reduce Locking and Contention
Transactions can introduce row-level or table-level locks depending on how they are used. If multiple queries are trying to access or modify the same rows concurrently within different transactions, it can lead to contention and delays.
Solution: Use Row-Level Locks or Optimistic Concurrency Control
If you suspect that locking is causing the slowdown, you can try using row-level locks (FOR UPDATE) or optimistic concurrency control to avoid unnecessary contention.
For example, you can lock rows explicitly when fetching them:
const data = await db.Operation.scope(
    isPause ? {} : { method: ['companyScope', req] }
).findByPk(req.params.id, {
    hooks: false,
    include: [
        {
            model: db.Task,
            as: 'task',
        },
    ],
    lock: t.LOCK.UPDATE, // Lock the row for update
    transaction: t,
});

This ensures that only one transaction can modify the row at a time.
4. Avoid Nested Transactions
If you're using nested transactions (i.e., starting a new transaction inside an existing one), it can lead to performance issues. Make sure you're not unintentionally nesting transactions by ensuring that all queries share the same transaction object.
In your case, you should pass the same transaction object (t) to all queries that need to be part of the same transaction:
await data.update(model, { transaction: t });
await resource.update({ lat, lng }, { transaction: t });
// Other queries using the same `t` object...

5. Monitor Connection Pool Usage
You can monitor how many connections are being used in your connection pool by accessing Sequelize’s pool properties:
console.log('Connections in use:', sequelize.connectionManager.pool.size);
console.log('Available connections:', sequelize.connectionManager.pool.available);

This will help you determine whether you're running out of available connections during peak loads.
6. Optimize Database Queries
Finally, ensure that your database queries are optimized. If certain queries are slow due to complex joins or missing indexes on frequently queried columns, they will take longer regardless of whether they're inside a transaction.
Solution:

Add indexes on columns like id, user_id, company_id, etc., that are frequently used in WHERE clauses.
Use query optimization tools provided by your database (e.g., EXPLAIN in MySQL/PostgreSQL).

Conclusion
The main issue seems to be related to how Sequelize handles transactions and connection pooling. Here's a summary of actions you can take:

Increase connection pool size to handle more concurrent requests.
Use managed transactions to simplify handling.
Investigate potential locking issues and use row-level locks where appropriate.
Ensure you're not unintentionally using nested transactions.
Monitor your connection pool usage.
Optimize your database queries for better performance.

By implementing these suggestions, you should be able to resolve the performance issue with your update endpoint when using transactions.

Thank you for this answer. I've tried all your suggestions but it still get stuck at te second update (resource). When I print the connection pols I get: Connections in use: 3 Available connections: 2 So I assume that is not a pool isse. The update query is pretty basic so I don't think that should be the issue too.
